# How to write Arabic text in a PDF using OpenPDF and Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, unicode, arabic, openpdf

I use OpenPDF to generate a PDF from a Spring Boot application. Everything works fine when I use French or English alphabets, but when I write in Arabic nothing is displayed.

I read that I have to use the Unicode form for the Arabic words. For example, the Arabic word **الاسم** converted to its Unicode form gives the following string:

`\u0627\u0644\u0627\u0633\u0645`

So I am wondering whether there is any way to convert Arabic words to Unicode in Java, and could I use that approach with OpenPDF? Or is there any alternative way to write Arabic in a PDF using OpenPDF and Java 17/Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This example of writing Arabic text to a PDF using OpenPDF](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/blob/bff6520a368fe0a35b443740a36cba108f4ed1a4/pdf-toolbox/src/test/java/com/lowagie/examples/fonts/styles/RightToLeft.java) solves my problem. (*RightToLeft.java* in the OpenPDF documentation.)

The main idea is to create a `BaseFont` that supports Arabic text, as shown on line 51:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\times.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
```

You can replace that **.ttf** file supporting Arabic text with your own file. You put it in the *resources* folder, and name it like this: *src/main/resources/youTtfFile.ttf*.

You also need to specify right to left (RTL) directionality, as shown on line 61:

```
ct.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
```